# Add / Subtract operations using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a simple HTML Add/Subtract table where the value doesn't go above 10 or below 0. I've setup two functions `additionalAdd` & `additionalSub` both setup using `onclick` to call them. But I keep getting the error saying `totalAddtions` not defined. Which is the variable I'm using to store the overall value.

```js
function additionalSub() {

  var totalAdditions = document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML;

  if (totalAddtions > 0) {
    totalAdditions--;
    document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML = totalAdditions;
  }

}

function additionalAdd() {

  var totalAdditions = document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML;

  if (totalAddtions < 10) {
    totalAdditions++;
    document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML = totalAdditions;
  }

}
```

```css
.btn {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.value {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Additional Expenses</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="value" id="additionalExpenses">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="btn" onclick="additionalSub()">
            <center>-</center>
          </td>
          <td class="btn" onclick="additionalAdd()">
            <center>+</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is just a typing error you use `totalAddtions` instead of totalAdd**i**tions

Comment: Hero! Thanks I didn't see that

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: Just to clarify HereticMonkeys comment @DaveTops javascript is NOT the same thing as Java. Java is a completely different language that runs on top of a virtual machine. JavaSCRIPT is the language of the web.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the if block

```
 var totalAdditions = document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML;

  if (totalAddtions > 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using spelling of totalAddtions wrong. And define it outside the function not inside it.

```js
 var totalAddtions=0;
function additionalSub() {
 totalAddtions = document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML;

  if (totalAddtions > 0) {
    totalAddtions--;
    document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML = totalAddtions;
  }
 

}

function additionalAdd() {

  totalAddtions = document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML;

  if (totalAddtions < 10) {
    totalAddtions++;
    document.getElementById("additionalExpenses").innerHTML = totalAddtions;
  }

}
```

```css
.btn {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.value {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">Additional Expenses</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" class="value" id="additionalExpenses">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="btn" onclick="additionalSub()">
            <center>-</center>
          </td>
          <td class="btn" onclick="additionalAdd()">
            <center>+</center>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```